# KVM guest halt to make the host kvm exit

Tags: kvm-virtualization, halt

I'm running Linux inside kvm. When I issue the `halt` command as root in the guest, eventually the guest halts with the kernel log message `System halted.`. However, the `kvm` host process keeps running. Is it possible to make it exit upon halt?

This looks like a relevant discussion: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.kvm.devel/107972

A related discussion, but it's about halting the guest from the host, but not from within: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1066940

A similar bugreport, with no meaningful response: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/967049

My kernel didn't have ACPI compiled in, so I've added support, but it still won't halt. This is what I get at boot time:

```
[    0.311211] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 11
[    0.312637] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKC] -> GSI 11 (level, high) -> IRQ 11
[    0.315049] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] enabled at IRQ 10
[    0.316472] virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKD] -> GSI 10 (level, high) -> IRQ 10
[    0.318858] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] enabled at IRQ 10
[    0.320254] virtio-pci 0000:00:05.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKA] -> GSI 10 (level, high) -> IRQ 10
```

ACPI kernel config:

```
CONFIG_ACPI=y
# CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_EC_DEBUGFS is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_PROC_EVENT is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_AC is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_BATTERY is not set
CONFIG_ACPI_BUTTON=y
# CONFIG_ACPI_FAN is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_DOCK is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_PROCESSOR is not set
CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_DSDT_FILE=""
# CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_DSDT is not set
CONFIG_ACPI_BLACKLIST_YEAR=0
# CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_PCI_SLOT is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_CONTAINER is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_SBS is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_HED is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_APEI is not set
CONFIG_PNPACPI=y
# CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_WMI is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_ASUS is not set
# CONFIG_ACPI_CMPC is not set
```

Update: `poweroff` works with an ACPI-enabled kernel (e.g. with the kernel config above). `halt` still doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, "poweroff" works just dandy for me. Never had a problem. I wouldn't really assume that "halt" turns off a machine either, it just stops it.

Answer (score 3):

Try running `halt -p`

`-p` tells the host to power off after the shutdown.

Specifically, the man page for `halt` states:

```
-p, --poweroff
       Instructs the halt command to instead behave as poweroff.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

```
 # shutdown -h now
```

Sometimes the ACPI daemon is not running, you might want to check that out as well.